# Having a new window show up on the proper monitor

Tags: ubuntu, xfce

Within the last week I have switched from Fedora 22 to Ubuntu 17.04, using xfce on both. On Fedora, when something I did caused a new window to pop up - for example, when I clicked to download a file, and a window popped to ask me where - the popped window would be on the same monitor (of 2) that the window I had clicked was on. Now, it always pops up on the primary monitor, regardless of which monitor has the focussed window.

In the process of customizing the new install, I *seem* to recall that there was a setting for this - something like 'always make new windows on primary monitor'. I haven't been able to find it again, and it's quite possible that I'm misremembering the existence of it.

I've tried websearch on 'window on primary monitor' and not been able to find anything useful. Is this a setting, and where is it? If not, is there some way I can convince the system to do this - to create a new (sub?) window on the same monitor that has the mouse?

Thanks
/amq